# Solving a system with circle equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, circles, nonlinear-system

I am stumped by this.  How do I solve algebraically, without graphing?

I've tried to solve for x in the second equation and substitute into the first. I'm not sure how else to do this. It just ends up being circular. xx+yy = 3xy or x/y + y/x = 3
Ultimately I figured it out by sketching a quick graph and noticing there must be two solutions, and there was no option with two solutions. I am suspect that there is a quicker/better way to do this problem which I am expected to know and understand.

Solve the system:

$ x^2 + y^2 = 15  $

$ xy = 5  $

$ y < 0 $

$\;\;$None of these

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar  I've tried to solve for x in the second equation and substitute into the first.  I'm not sure how else to do this.  

Ultimately I figured it out by sketching a quick graph and noticing there must be two solutions, and there was no option with two solutions.  I am suspect that there is a quicker/better way to do this problem which I am expected to know and understand.

Comment: Yes you substitute into the first. What do you get when you do that (in your question you specifically asks for algebraic method, so lets stick to this one)

Comment: Try adding twice the second equation to the first.

Comment: It just ends up being circular.   xx+yy = 3xy

 or x/y + y/x = 3

Comment: What you get when you substitute values from a) and b) ?

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, that is helpful.  So is the logic here that I know there are exactly two solutions, so I should be able to deduce that every listed answer is incorrect?

Comment: Please edit your post, @Rose, so users do not have to pull teeth to learn more about what your know and what you tried.  That's your job, to include that information *in the question*, to start with, or to later edit your question.  As it is, your question is a mandate in which you *tell* us to solve a system for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you can add and substract $2xy$ from the first equation:
$$x^2+y^2 = 15 \Longrightarrow x^2+2xy+y^2-2xy=15 \Longrightarrow (x+y)^2-2xy = 15$$
And since $xy=5 \Longrightarrow (x+y)^2=25 \Longrightarrow (x+y) =5 $ Or, $(x+y)=-5$.

Assume $(x+y)=5,$ then $x=5-y$, we can set it in the second equation to get:
$$(5-y)y=5 \Longrightarrow -y^2+5y+5=0$$
There are 2 real positve solutions to this equation, and since $y<0$ it is not a solution to the equation.

Let's try $(x+y)=-5$, in the same way:
$$x=-5-y \Longrightarrow-y^2-5y-5=0 \iff y=-\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2} \space \space OR\space \space -\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Both solutions satisfy $y<0$ and thus they are both solutions.
We can set this values in the 2nd equation to get that the solutions are:
$$\left(-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2},-\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right),\left(-\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2} , -\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @RoseMullins Something I've learned is that whenever you see something which is close to $a^2+2ab+b^2$ try completing it by adding and substracting, helped me many times.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

One possible way, let $x=\frac{5}{y}$ and substitute into the first equation.

$$\frac{25}{y^2}+y^2=15$$

$$25+(y^2)^2=15y^2$$

Can you solve for $y^2$ using quadratic equation?

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I can.  However I don't think this is the method we are supposed to use (this is a college algebra class in US).  We haven't learned any so-called "u-substitution" in this course.  I'm just concerned that there is a concept I'm not aware of that I'm expected to know which I've failed to learn

Comment: You might like to edit your question describing more about what have you learned.

Comment: Siong: that comment belonged under the question, prior to answering, and waiting until the question is improved, before ever answering.